# Getting error Uncaught Error: Assert failed: Reaction is read only; on-set is not allowed

Tags: clojure, single-page-application, clojurescript, reagent, re-frame

I am new to clojure and reagent. I was trying to generate dynamic number of checkboxes, the state of which is stored in the app state which is a list of dicts like this

`[{:checked false, :text "Sample text 1"} {:checked false, :text "Sample text 2"} {:checked false, :text "Sample text 3"}]`

The function below is expected to generate a checkbox corresponding to the specified index of app's db (`db`). The function does it jobs and the checkboxes are clickable.

```
(defn gen-checkbox [index db] 
     [re-com/checkbox
            :label (:text (@db index))
            :model (:checked (@db index))
            :on-change #(swap! db assoc-in [index :checked] (not(:checked (@db index))))
     ])
```

However, I get this error in the browser console when I click on any checkbox.

```
Uncaught Error: Assert failed: Reaction is read only; on-set is not allowed
```

The error occurs at `swap!`. Can some one point out what I am doing wrong?

The db initialization part is as below:

```
(re-frame/reg-event-db ::initialize-db 
   (fn [_ _] 
      (atom [{:checked false :text "Sample text"}, {:checked false :text "Sample text"}, {:checked false :text "Sample text"}])
   ))
```

I also have a function to retreive the db. I am currently getting

```
(re-frame/reg-sub ::getdb 
   (fn [db]
      @db
   ))
```

Comment: Do you have an extra set of parentheses around the `:on-change` anonymous function?

Comment: @exupero that was a typo. I have corrected it. However, the error remains the same.

Comment: Can you please show the part of the code that deals with your `db`? How do you store it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Based on the tags of your question, I presume that you are using re-frame.

You [can't update the database in re-frame directly](https://github.com/Day8/re-frame/blob/master/docs/INTRO.md). Instead, you should register an event handler that updates the database, like the below (the exact code depends on the structure of your DB):

```
;; (require '[re-frame.core :as rf])

(rf/reg-event-db
 :toggle-checkbox
 (fn [db [_ index]]
   (update-in db [index :checked] not)))
```

And then dispatch the event in the code of your checkbox's renderer:

```
...
:on-change #(rf/dispatch [:toggle-checkbox index])
...
```

Comment: Thanks Aleph :). However, I am hitting a new error now: 
No protocol method IDeref.-deref defined for type cljs.core/PersistentVector: [{:checked false, :text "Sample text"} {:checked false, :text "Sample text"} {:checked true, :text "Sample text"}]

I have updated the snippet with the part of code that initializes the db as you suggested.

Comment: You should make sure that you are not dereferencing your DB subscription twice. If the `db` parameter of `gen-checkbox` already contains dereferenced subscription, you should not add `@` in the function body: `... :label (:text (get db index)) :model (:checked (get db index))`